# How can I run the debugger on jupyter while using VSC and python 3.6?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-3.6, vscode-debugger

I want to run the debugger, but I must use python version 3.6 because I need to run an external software that requires it.

I have followed these indications:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Setting-Up-Run-by-Line-and-Debugging-for-Notebooks

They say, I must have python 3.7 or grater. Is there any other way in which I can run the debugger with jupyter and python 3.6?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the the same issue. Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Hey, did anyone get a workaround for this?